# Why isn't my cancellation token killing this job?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, cancellation

I believe I create and immediately cancel a task below. Yet, when running the below code, you'll note it spins forever. What gives? Why doesn't attaching `src.Token` cause the cancellation?

```
CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task t = Task.Run(()=> 
                  {
                      while (true) 
                      { 
                          Thread.Sleep(100); 
                      } 
                  },
                  src.Token);

Thread.Sleep(1000);
src.Cancel();
t.Wait();
```

Comment: `CancellationToken`s **don't** _"kill"_ anything.  There are merely a way of politely indicating to something that they should _cancel_ at their ealiest convenience.  For this to work, the child thread needs to monitor the `IsCancellationRequested` flag.  Inside your `while` loop is the perfect spot

Comment: Because your while loop doesn't check the `CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested` Property.

Comment: So this seems to do it `Task t = Task.Run(()=> {while (!src.IsCancellationRequested) { Thread.Sleep(100); } },src.Token);`, but how do I access the token associated with the task, rather than using the overall scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `Task.Run` will be cancelled only if the token has been canceled before the task execution begun:

```
CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
src.Cancel();
Task t = Task.Run(()=> 
                  {
                      while (true) 
                      { 
                          Thread.Sleep(100); 
                      } 
                  },
                  src.Token);

Thread.Sleep(1000);
t.Wait();
```

You can read more about this case in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Run_System_Action_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

The alternative way is to pass the cancellation token to the `Wait` method:

```
CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task t = Task.Run(()=> {while (true) { Thread.Sleep(100); } },src.Token);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
src.Cancel();
t.Wait(src.Token);
```

In this case it behaves in exactly the same way as `Task.Run` does: "The wait terminates if a cancellation token is canceled before the task completes." (c) [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

And the proper way to handle a cancellation is to check for the token state on each iteration of your long-running task:

```
CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
Task t = Task.Run(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        src.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}, src.Token);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
src.Cancel();
t.Wait();
```

Comment: You probably should mention that in your _"alternative way"_, the job continues to run.  Using the token in the `Wait()` merely unblocks the calling thread when the token is signalled.  Kudos for using `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` which is very important for chained `Task`s.  +1

Comment: Thanx, @MickyD, this is the good point. Yes, it unblocks the thread but it doesn't stop the long-running job from executing (`while` loop keep being alive).